# What return boost::geometry::intersection?

Tags: c++, boost

I can not find description of return value of `boost::geometry::intersection` in boost documentation. So I do not understand what it means. Here is minimal example:

```cpp
// main.cpp

#include <boost/geometry/algorithms/intersection.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/box.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/ring.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/views/box_view.hpp>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

int main() {
  namespace geometry = boost::geometry;
  using Point        = geometry::model::d2::point_xy<int>;
  using Box          = geometry::model::box<Point>;
  using Ring         = geometry::model::ring<Point>;

  Box box1{Point{0, 0}, Point{10, 10}};
  Box box2{Point{20, 20}, Point{30, 30}};

  std::list<Ring> intersections;
  bool            s = geometry::intersection(
      geometry::box_view{box1}, geometry::box_view{box2}, intersections);
  bool s1 =
      geometry::intersects(geometry::box_view{box1}, geometry::box_view{box2});

  std::cout << std::boolalpha << s << std::endl;
  std::cout << std::boolalpha << s1 << std::endl;
  std::cout << intersections.size() << std::endl;

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

It produced next output:

```
true
false
0
```

Why `intersection` return `true` even if two geometries not intersects? Why retval of `intersection` and `intersects` is different? What it means?

Thank

Comment: "Intersects" [returns true if two geometries intersect each other](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/intersects/intersects_2_two_geometries.html), intersection returns true if the operation finished successfully (afai can see  not in the docs, but looks like it from looking at the source code)